# ChatGPT API integration in a WordPress custom HTML block

Tags: html, wordpress, web, chatgpt-api

I have a website built on a WordPress business account.

On one of the pages, I want to include ChatGPT API inside a custom HTML block.
However, all my attempts at doing that have failed.

I have tried several different HTML scripts for the integration of the API, but nothing is working since after publishing, there is empty output.

What is the latest working and tested solution for the same for integrating the API on WordPress inside a custom HTML block?

Note: I am not interested in using any ChatGPT AI plugins that are already available.

These are the different HTML scripts I tried inside the custom HTML code block:

##### 1.

```
<div id="chatgpt-container"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@openai/chatgpt@1.0.0/dist/chatgpt.js"></script>
<script>
  const apiKey = "YOUR API KEY"; // replace with your actual ChatGPT API key
  const chatgptContainer = document.getElementById("chatgpt-container");
  const chatbot = new ChatGPT({
    apiKey: apiKey,
    container: chatgptContainer,
    welcomeMessage: "Hi there! How can I assist you today?",
    placeholder: "Type your message here...",
    theme: "light"
  });
  chatbot.init();
</script>
```

##### 2.

```
<div id="chatgpt-widget"></div>

<script>
  (function() {
    var chatgptScript = document.createElement('script');
    chatgptScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    chatgptScript.async = true;
    chatgptScript.src = 'https://cdn.openai.com/api/chatwidget.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(chatgptScript, s);
  })();

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var chatgpt = window.chatWidget({
      apiKey: 'YOUR API KEY',
      title: 'Chat with us!',
      subtitle: 'Powered by OpenAI',
      placeholderText: 'Type a message...',
      container: document.getElementById('chatgpt-widget')
    });
  });
</script>
```

Both of these are throwing empty outputs at preview/publish.

Expected output at preview: A placeholder where user can input text and then there will be a response generated by the ChatGPT API based on that.

Comment: Perhaps this may be worth reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/4961700

Comment: neither of those script sources are live (the unpkg and cdn sources). @SolarMike SO's stance on GPT-generated content on SO has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Yulian So? I suggested it might be worth reading. And it is the Stack's stance, I did not state a stand either way - that is your opportunity to sate your not define mine.

Comment: Have you replaced the "YOUR API KEY" with your API key? Are there any notices in the console or errors?